# Where does make's 'include' find files?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

This seems (and probably is) obvious but I can't find it.

Where does make's [include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) look for the file to include? Like this:

```
# /mydir/makefile
include basemakefile
```

where the file `basemakefile` is located somewhere else that I don't want to hard-code. Updating `$PATH` doesn't work for me.

**EDIT**: what I was really looking for was an environment variable to control this. There is no `PATH`, but as [Etan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) suggests you can use `MAKEFLAGS=-I/my/path/`. Whether you should want to abuse `MAKEFLAGS` like that is questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very section of the manual you linked to:

> If the specified name does not start with a slash, and the file is not found in the current directory, several other directories are searched. First, any directories you have specified with the ‘-I’ or ‘--include-dir’ option are searched (see Summary of Options). Then the following directories (if they exist) are searched, in this order: *prefix*/include (normally /usr/local/include) /usr/gnu/include, /usr/local/include, /usr/include.

Comment: So there is no environment variable I could set to control this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You *might* be able to use `vpath`/`VPATH` here also but I wouldn't bet on it (I half expect it might work to find the makefile to rebuild, and its prereqs, but then fail to load it).

Comment: Oh, I suppose `MAKEFLAGS=-I ...` counts as an "environment variable".

Comment: No, and I wouldn't recommend it either.

Comment: @EtanReisner why would you not recommend it Etan :)  It's in the GNU Make manual, specifically talks about assignment to `MAKEFLAGS` in the environment, exactly for this kind of situation.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Because presumably in whatever environment you are needing to do this you could just as easily have added those as command line arguments instead and not depended on potentially random environmental state. Or alternatively have put that in the Makefile (or an generated/included makefile) instead (I'm assuming that works).

Answer (score 2):

Etan's comment is the correct answer, for the edited version of the question.  Do this in your environment

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-I/my/path
```

This is not abuse, it is a normal use of the variable `MAKEFLAGS`, covered in the GNU Make Manual.

Comment: I'm sort-of shocked you are ok with dependence on environmental factors for your builds functionality. (I mean I know you've said your environments are very controlled but still.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes! Very much so.  I made up a saying "calling Make without a wrapper is like riding a horse without a saddle - possible but painful".  I always have a wrapper, which sets up all the environment that might have any impact on the behaviour of Make, then calls Make, then filters the output (syntax coloring and diagnostics).  All users must call the wrapper.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have to do it like that - I don't write makefiles for my own projects, but as a consultant, I write a system for possibly hundreds of engineers to use, then they call me for support.  I have to put in the manual, no deleting of files by hand, no calling Make without a wrapper, and such things, otherwise, if you do these things, you better know what you are doing, because I am not going to support you.  When you did something you were not supposed to do and unexpected behaviour occurs, make clean and start over.

Comment: Ah, you've mentioned that before. In that sense that's basically like putting it in the makefile (which I do think makes sense as a system) so in that case it is entirely reasonable. I was thinking more ad-hoc environment flag usage but I guess I should have known better than to think you meant that.